# How I get the total number of complete all elements in an JSON Object?

Tags: json, javascript-objects

for example:

```
var jsonArray = {
```

'-1': {
    '-1': 'b',
    '2': 'a',
    '10': 'c'
  },
  '2': {
    '-1': 'a',
    '2': 'b',
    '10': 'a'
  },
  '5': {
    '-1': 'a',
    '2': 'a',
    '10': 'b'
  }
};

I want to have a solution that have 21 or 18 as result. That means keys and values.

Comment: Why 21 / 18? What are you trying to do? You are not asking question

Comment: _a solution that have 21 or 18 as result..._ Huh? What is the magical logic behind that?

Comment: I have 21 elements:
-1,-1, b, 2,a, 10, c, 2, -1, a, 2, b, 10 , a, 5, -1, a, 2, a, 10, b.

Comment: I really want to down vote you..... And you don't have 21 elements

Comment: if these are not elements, how do you call that tom10271?
18 in braces, 3 outside

Comment: If you are asking for the total number of keys and values, then yes the total number will be 21.

Comment: But what are you trying to do? It does not make sense

Comment: And how about array? Primitive, object and mixed array?

Comment: I want to know if the object is complete, because it is generated many times with different data.
Sometimes a few values are missing. That has to be intercepted. Understandable?
This is an example, the actual object is significantly larger.

Answer (score 1):

```js
/*
function count(objectValues){
    var count = 0;
    objectValues.forEach(elt => count += Object.values(elt).length + Object.keys(elt).length);
    return count;
} */
function countrec(objectValues){
        if(typeof objectValues !== "object"){
            return 1;
        }
        var count = Object.keys(objectValues).length;
        Object.values(objectValues).forEach(elt => count += countrec(elt));
        return count;
    }

    var jsonArray = {
        '-1': { '-1': 'b', '2': 'a', '10': 'c' }, '2': { '-1': 'a', '2': 'b', '10': 'a' }, '5': { '-1': 'a', '2': 'a', '10': 'b' } 
    };
    
    console.log(countrec(jsonArray));
```

Comment: very, very nice. Thank you romph. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: This is very rigid

Comment: count also the undefined elements.But I have a good approach to completing